# SimplePager wrong display of elements count

Tags: gwt

[JAVA]

I'm Using a CellTable and a SimplePager, getting data in my dataprovider over RPC. Works great.

The pager is displaying for example "14-28 of 120", wich is correct. 
When the query returns zero elements to display, the pager displays "1-1 of 0", even when I use `my_cellTable.setRowCount(0);`

How do I get it to display "0 of 0" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is this problem. To fix the issue you need to create own custom pager. Extend  `SimplePager` and override the method `createText()`. For example:

```
public class MySimplePager extends SimplePager {
    @Override
    protected String createText() {
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getFormat("#,###");
        HasRows display = getDisplay();
        Range range = display.getVisibleRange();
        int pageStart = range.getStart() + 1;
        int pageSize = range.getLength();
        int dataSize = display.getRowCount();
        int endIndex = Math.min( dataSize, pageStart + pageSize - 1);
        endIndex = Math.max(pageStart, endIndex);
        boolean exact = display.isRowCountExact();
        if (dataSize == 0) {
           return "0 of 0";
        } else if (pageStart == endIndex) {
                 return formatter.format(pageStart) 
                        + " of "
                        + formatter.format(dataSize);
        }
        return formatter.format(pageStart)
            + "-"
            + formatter.format(endIndex)
            + (exact ? " of " : " of over ")
            + formatter.format(dataSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of a bug on my side. The next time I'll check the sources before..

Answer (score 0):

What I did is just to set the pager's visibility to false when the number of elements is 0.

Comment: Good idea but your solution is not a bugfix, but a workaround. And workarounds are not good when you need stable software.